# Relationship with double summing of $a_{\ell m}$

Tags: cosmology, operators, astrophysics, correlation-functions, wick-theorem

I would like to convince myself of the following relationship in an astrophysical context:

\begin{aligned} 
& \sum_{m}\sum_{m^{\prime}}\left\langle a_{\ell m} a_{\ell m}^* a_{\ell m^{\prime}} a_{\ell m^{\prime}}^*\right\rangle \\ 
& =\left[\sum_m\left\langle a_{\ell m} a_{\ell m}^* a_{\ell m} a_{\ell m}^*\right\rangle+\sum_{m^{\prime}\neq m} \left\langle a_{\ell m} a_{\ell m}^* a_{\ell m^{\prime}} a_{\ell m^{\prime}}^*\right\rangle\right] \\
& =\left(3 C_{\ell}^2(2 \ell+1)+2 \ell C_{\ell}^2(2 \ell+1)\right).
\end{aligned}

I apply Wick's theorem for computing the expectation of $a_{\ell m} $:

[image: Wick's theorem]

**EDIT 1:** I think that my issue of understanding is about the second sum when $m\neq m'$. I can't represent myself the number of terms in this sum ( equal to $2\ell\ \times(2\ell +1)$)

**EDIT 2:** I think the keypoint is the number of different pairs ($m,m^{\prime}$).

$A_{n}^{p}= \dfrac{(2\ell+1)!}{(2\ell-1)!}= (2\ell+1)\times 2\ell$

Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Are those supposed to be steps in an equality that just happens to be missing the all-important equals sign? Or is it a product of terms? What are $a_{\ell m}$? And $C_\ell$?

Comment: You seem to be summing over *m* s twice?

Comment: @CosmasZachos .yes since I compute the case $m=m^{\prime}$n is it right ?

Comment: Illustrate this to yourself by *m* ranging over 1, 2. What do you get?

Comment: @KyleKanos . Sorry, the definition of a $$C_{\ell}=\dfrac{1}{2 \ell+1} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{+\ell}\left|a_{\ell m}\right|^{2}$$